# Processing server response with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, html-parsing

I receive a string data from a server in the format that includes HTML tags. How do I convert the string into a readable text and make the HTML tags count (emphasize text, make line breaks etc.)

`"<p>Some paragraph... </p>\r\n<p><strong>Some text here</strong>&nbsp;And text here as well <br />`

Comment: What does "make the HTML tags count" mean? What is your expected output?

Comment: I mean that any text inside <strong> tag turns into bold, <br /> inserts a line break, &deg; gets converted to  ° etc.

Comment: How should your readable text be formatted in bold? With ANSI escape codes, as Markdown or as PDF output?

Comment: I'm making an async request to a server to get products. Products descriptions are strings that have HTML tags in them. For instance subtitles are in <strong> tag. I'm wondering is there a built-in JS function or a 3rd party library that can process the HTML tags so that the text get formatted in accordance with the tags. So that instead of <strong> I am a text </strong> I could render simply I am a text in bold

Comment: Yes, I get what you're trying to achieve. What I don't understand is the output format you want to use. Maybe something like [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text) could do the job, but formatting in **bold** gets complicated.